# Open Base64 in Browser with Intent

Tags: java, android, base64

i want to know if there is a way to open a Base64 with predefined MIME type with browser Intent. I have try something like this based on Android Studio Official Documentation :

```
    String url = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,[myBase64]"
    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

If i try to paste `url` into chrome, it automatically prompt a download window, but when i try above code, i got error like this

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,[myBase64]
```

It seems that my `url` didn't accepted as valid url, how can i get my file from `[mybase64]` with browser intent ? any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: That is no url indeed.

Comment: @blackapps, yes indeed it is not a valid url, since it doesn't contain something like "http://". but if i paste the entire ```url``` into chrome and click enter, a download prompt will appear. So i think even it is not a valid url i still can treat it like a url

Comment: Using Chrome or most other browsers nowadays you never have to type the https:// anymore. It is cared for and used.

Comment: And Chrome is not even started. Or another app. Dont blame Chrome. Its Android OS that refuses this intent.

Comment: @blackapps, yes that's the point, if chrome can handle my ```url``` directly, the problem is lie within ```Uri.parse```. That's why i ask

Comment: No. Uri.parse() does nothing. Only makes the string an uri. It will even make an uri of the wetter forecast. You start with a wrong url. If you want to invoke Chrome than start your url with http:// or https://.

Answer (score 0):

As you say your url is not valid. I don't know if my answer is accurate, but reading it is entirely like a single string, so '[myBase64]' doesn't say anything.

Try **concatenating your base64 file in it**.

You need to remove the "data:image/png;base64,":

```
String imageB64 = url.substring(22);
byte[] decodedStr = Base64.decode(imageB64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

---

[Documentation of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW).

Source: [Opening a URL in Android's web browser from within application](http://programming.guide/java/open-url-in-androids-web-browser.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer. First i think if i need to get rid of ```data:[MIMEtype]``` i think it is safer to use ```split(",")``` than use ```substring(22)```. And second, after i get the ```decodedStr```, how can i prompt user to open the file ?

Comment: I do not see a file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what is the required behavior. Do you want to download the file? If yes, you need to use `Download Manager` API for that.

If you need to open the file and let the Android OS select the appropriate application to open your intent, then you can set the mime type of your intent to spreadsheet first.